# How to publish and position an article in joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla

I have created an article in joomla2.5 , when i try to publish it, it's not reflecting in front end. 
I am a newbie to joomla2.5. Any help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go in the article manager:

http://docs.joomla.org/Screen.content.15

Then click on the little red icon in the "featured article" column (it used to be the "front page" column in versions previous to 1.7), the icon should become green.

To decide the order of the articles in home page, use the Featured Articles manager (it used to be the front page manager in the previous versions)

http://docs.joomla.org/Help17:Content_Featured_Articles

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Some how i mapped the menu to a article and able to display it in front end. But i am facing a error. “Notice: Undefined property: ContentViewFeatured::$print” Any help on this?

Comment: It's just a notice, not an error. The problem is probably related to the template you chose. Anyway, since it's just a notice, you may want to turn off notices by going in Configuration > Server > Error Reporting and selecting "None".